# Deconvoluting an ECDF via mixed modeling

Tags: mixed-model, robust, measurement-error, semiparametric

I have data with measurement error, $W_i$, with the following structure:

$$W_i = \mu + \gamma_i + U_i$$

where $U_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2_i)$, with known $\sigma^2_i$, and $U_i \; \amalg \; \gamma_i$. I do not want to make any assumptions on the distribution of $\gamma_i$.

That is,  $X_i := \mu + \gamma_i$ is the unobserved true mean for observation $i$, and $W_i$ is measured with normal, heteroskedastic error. **My goal is to estimate the CDF of the underlying variables $X_i$.**

I have read about some quite complicated approaches to deconvolution [1-3], and I think their complexity reflects that they try to accommodate a more general framework than what I have. Additionally, I'm finding that the only one of these methods that provides code does not work well in practice with normal error (an issue to which [2] also alludes).

I think it should be possible to answer my question by fitting some kind of semiparametric linear mixed model, given the structure I’ve written above. The trick is that I would need to be able to make parametric assumptions on the $U_i$ but none at all on the $\gamma_i$, and in order to estimate the CDF, I would need estimates (e.g., from empirical Bayes) for each $\gamma_i$, not just $\mu$.

**My questions are: 
(1) Is my simpler LMM approach valid?
(2) If so, how can I fit it in R, including getting estimates for each $\gamma_i$?
(3)  If not, is there another simple approach to deconvolution in this case?**

#### References

[1] Wang, X. F., & Wang, B. (2011). Deconvolution estimation in measurement error models: the R package decon. *Journal of Statistical Software*, 39(10).

[2] Staudenmayer, J., Ruppert, D., & Buonaccorsi, J. P. (2008). Density estimation in the presence of heteroscedastic measurement error. *Journal of the American Statistical Association*, 103(482), 726-736.

[3] Stefanski, L. A., & Bay, J. M. (1996). Simulation extrapolation deconvolution of finite population cumulative distribution function estimators. *Biometrika*, 83(2), 407-417.